# Magento 2 - Add XML Block inside product.info in Product Page

Tags: magento2, layout

I'm trying to add a custom block as a child block to product.info (inside the form of the add to cart) so I add the following code to **app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="testing" template="Magento_Cms::test.phtml" />
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

not working, no change.
Magento 2, developer mode is on, cleared cache, deployed files etc.

any Ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you want override a page in Magento 2. You don't change `name` at

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="testing" template="Magento_Cms::test.phtml" />
```

of it. It word for me.

Comment: this is not an override of a page.. it's a custom new page. also this is just an example... I also tried insert there a static block and other elements.. non of them were rendered.